# How to display data in webi cross table?

Tags: crosstab, webi

I have the below data

```
F1  F2  F3
1   V1  11
2   V1  21
2   V2  22
3   V1  31
3   V3  33
4   V2  42
4   V3  43
5   V1  51
5   V2  52
5   V3  53
```

And I would like to display it as below:

```
    V1  V2  V3
1   11      
2   21  22  
3   31      33
4       42  43
5   51  52  53
```

However, the cross table in Webi displays as below:

```
    V1  V2  V3
1   11  11  11
2   21  21  21
2   22  22  22
3   31  31  31
3   33  33  33
4   42  42  42
4   43  43  43
5   51  51  51
5   52  52  52
5   53  53  53
```

Anyone could show me how to do that. Many thanks.

Andre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object in the field of your crosstab (not the columns or row headers) needs to be a measure. Initially, I thought you could get around this by checking the "Avoid duplicate row aggregation" within the properties of your table, but that does not quite meet the objective.

[image]

To test this out I created a report based on FHSQL (free-hand SQL). Here is my SQL to generate your dataset...

```
SELECT '1' AS [F1], 'V1' AS [F2], '11' AS [F3]
UNION
SELECT '2', 'V1', '21'
UNION
SELECT '2', 'V2', '22'
UNION
SELECT '3', 'V1', '31'
UNION
SELECT '3', 'V3', '33'
UNION
SELECT '4', 'V2', '42'
UNION
SELECT '4', 'V3', '43'
UNION
SELECT '5', 'V1', '51'
UNION
SELECT '5', 'V2', '52'
UNION
SELECT '5', 'V3', '53';
```

Now that I actually had the exact data to work with I could experiment more fully. The first step is to create a variable that is the maximum of **F3**.

```
[Max F3]=Max([F3])
```

Place **Max F3** in the field of your crosstab replacing **F3**. Now *instead* of checking "Avoid duplicate row aggregation" on the properties of your crosstab you need to check "Show rows/columns with empty dimension values".

The table on the left shows the raw data. The table in the middle is the crosstab with the duplicated data that you get by default which you do not want. Finally, the table on the right is the crosstab using the **Max F3** defined above and the "Show rows/columns with empty dimension values" checked.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your hint. More info, the field F3 is a dimension, not a measure. Your instruction helps me remove duplicates on rows, but it doesn't merge rows sharing the same row header into one row. May I know how to achieve the final outcome. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks Isaac for your help. I created a measure variable for the field and the cross table works as expected.